# Do we say something for affect or effect?

Tags: word-choice, confusable

Do we say something for *affect* or *effect*?

For instance, if I give the description of a *round ball*, it seems that the word *round* is redundant; however, I have chosen to combine those words "for *affect*/*effect*"?

In researching this, all I could find is the usual definitions of *affect* and *effect*: *affect* is a verb and *effect* is a noun; however, in with my understanding of English, it seems that they can be used interchangeably in the aforementioned phrase?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/affect-as-a-noun is related but probably not a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable. Here, *for* takes a noun, not a verb (bare infinitive). So your choices are the nouns *affect* and *effect*. *Affect* (noun) is uncommon (in everyday use). It seems to be a psychological term given. The dictionary gives

> [affect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect)
>   1. the conscious subjective aspect of an emotion considered apart from bodily changes; also :  a set of observable manifestations of a subjectively experienced emotion <*… patients … showed perfectly normal reactions and affects … — Oliver Sacks*>

This doesn't match the desired meaning. The answer is effect (noun):

> [effect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect)
>   7. b :  the creation of a desired impression <*her tears were purely for effect*>

So in your example, you want to say *round ball* for *the creation of a desired impression*, whatever that may be.

Comment: "Affect" as a noun was imported into English from the German noun "Affekt", meaning "feeling" or "emotion". There are occasional uses in English well before psychology became a science. In German, it was already used as a technical term to describe the interpretation and performance of music by 1750, and probably earlier. It occasionally appears in English writing about music from the same date.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a noun *affect*, which I didn't find out until I got to college and did some study of the psychology of music.  The noun *affect* means "an expressed or observed emotional response."

While either noun could be used correctly, I would use *effect*. The term *for effect* is idiomatic and generally understood, and the use of *affect* as a noun is very rare, generally limited to textbooks on psychology.

Here are the different meanings of *affect* and *effect*:

> *Effect* as a noun: something that is produced as a result or a consequence of something else.  The loud noise had an *effect* on my hearing.
>
> *Effect* as a verb: to cause to happen.  By climbing down a tree by the window, I *effected* my escape from the burning house.
>
> *Affect* as a verb: to have an effect on something.  The loud noise *affected* my hearing.
>
> *Affect* as a noun: already explained above.  "Emotion or *affect* is aroused when a tendency to respond is arrested or inhibited."  (Leonard B. Meyer, *Emotion and Meaning in Music*, University of Chicago Press, 1956.)