# affect vs effect

Tags: word-usage, confusable

I a bit confuse on these two words. 
As far I know:

> **Affect** means to influence or to produce a change in something.
>
> **Effect** means the result of a change.

To make sure I understand their differences correctly, I came up with these examples:

1. Will my app get **effected** if this line of code get removed?
2. Will this changes **affect** my code?

Are these example correct?

Comment: Related question: [Do we say something for affect or effect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116686/9161)

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of native English speakers can't get this right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they should be:

> 1. Will my app **be affected** if this line of code **gets** removed?
> 2. Will **these** changes affect my code?

---

Part of the confusion may be that **effect** can be used as a noun or a verb; **affect** can only (usually)<sup>1</sup> be used as a verb.

- **effect** as a noun - Refers to how something is changed or behaves differently as a result of an action. "All actions have an effect."
- **effect** as a verb - Means to cause something to happen. "Activists want to effect change in policy."
- **affect** (only a verb) - Means to change, alter or have an impact on something else. "Changes in policy affect all of us."

<sup>1</sup> "Affect" [*can* be used as a noun](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/affect_2), but this usage is very rare. As a learner it's probably best not to worry about this.

Comment: Taking it one step further, and applying your facts to the OP's examples, we could say: _What **effect** will these changes have on my code?_

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by TypeIA, both Affect and Effect can be either a verb or a noun, depending on usage. However, Effect (verb) is very uncommon and Affect (noun) is almost nonexistent (I have never actually seen it used outside of examples). For now, I would suggest ignoring them entirely; they will just complicate things and make it all more confusing. So, for the time being, just remember that **Effect=Noun** ("*a sound effect*") and **Affect=Verb** ("*bad speakers affect the sound*").

Keep in mind: only verbs can change tense, so Affected and Affecting are both valid, but Effected and Effecting are not. On the other hand, nouns can be counted, so "an effect", "3 effects", "any effect", "all the effects", etc. work just fine, but you cannot have "3 affects". If you are unsure, see if you can modify the sentence a bit to use one of the above examples and it should become more clear.

> *Incorrect* "What **affect** will removing this line of code have on my app?" -> "What **affects** *[plural]* will removing this line of code have on my app?" (oh no! Affect cannot be plural!)
>
> *Correct* "What **effect** will removing this line of code have on my app?" -> "What **effects** *[plural]* will removing this line of code have on my app?" (ah, much better!)
>
> *Incorrect:* "Will these changes **effect** my code?" -> "These changes **effected** my code!" (whoops! Effected isn't a word! (sort of...))
>
> *Correct:* "Will these changes **affect** my code?" -> "These changes **affected** my code!" (yay! It works!)

Comment: I've heard affect as a noun in psychology (e.g. "flat affect"), but it's a technical term and not something the average layperson will encounter. OTOH, effect as a verb is not all that rare, although certainly rarer than the two usages you describe. But effect-as-a-noun has a totally different meaning, so I don't imagine it's particularly helpful to avoid learning it.

Comment: @Kevin I think it is important to learn one step at a time. We are taught "I before E" first, because it covers most of the cases we will encounter early on. Then we learn "except after C" followed by "and in cases of 'ay' as in 'neighbor' and 'weigh'". Getting all the variations and exceptions thrown at you at once can be overwhelming and discouraging. I am not trying to suggest that it is beneficial to pretend they don't exist at all, but rather to not worry about the edge cases when starting out.

Comment: Actually, [they don't teach that any more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duqlZXiIZqA). I really don't see the benefit in pretending that a perfectly good word does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Affect is typically used as a verb, and it means to influence or produce a change in something. For example, "The new medication will affect her mood." In this sentence, affect is used to convey that the medication will produce a change in the person's mood.
>
> On the other hand, effect is typically used as a noun, and it refers to the result or the consequence of a specific action. For example, "The new policy had a positive effect on employee morale." In this sentence, effect is used to convey the result or consequence of the new policy on employee morale.

Taken from [here](https://powerdreamer.com/blog/affect-vs-effect)

Comment: That article has extremely repetitive wording that sounds like AI (which is what the company is trying to sell you elsewhere on their site). Not great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).